# Plotting boxplot with sns

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I would like to depict the value of my variables found in a dataset in the form of a boxplot. The dataset is the following:

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/breast+cancer+wisconsin+(original)

So far my code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn import preprocessing

df=pd.read_csv(file,names=['id', 'clump_thickness','unif_cell_size',
                                                         'unif_cell_shape', 'marg_adhesion', 'single_epith_cell_size',
                                                         'bare_nuclei', 'bland_chromatin', 'normal_nucleoli','mitoses','Class'])

#boxplot
    plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
    names=list(df.columns)
    names=names[:-1]
    
    min_max_scaler=preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
    
    
    X = df.drop(["Class"],axis=1)
    columnsN=list(X.columns) 
    x_scaled=min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X) #normalization
    X[columnsN]=x_scaled 
    y = df['Class']
    
    sns.set_context('notebook', font_scale=1.5)
    sns.boxplot(x=X['unif_cell_size'],y=y,data=df.iloc[:, :-1],orient="h")
```

My boxplot returns the following figure:

[image]

but I would like to display my information like the following graph:

[image]

I know that is from a different dataset, but I can see that they have displayed the diagnosis, at the same time, for each feature with their values. I have tried to do it in different ways, but I am not able to do that graph.

I have tried the following:

```
data_st = pd.concat([y,X],axis=1)
    data_st = pd.melt(data_st,id_vars=columnsN,
                    var_name="X",
                    value_name='value')
    
    sns.boxplot(x='value', y="X", data=data_st,hue=y,palette='Set1')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
```

but still no results.

Answer (score 0):

### Reshape the data with `pandas.DataFrame.melt`:

- Most of the benign (class 2) boxplots are at 0 (scaled) or 1 (unscaled), as they should be

  - `print(df_scaled_melted.groupby(['Class', 'Attributes', 'Values'])['Values'].count().unstack())` after `melt`, to understand the counts
- `MinMaxScaler` has been used, but is unnecessary in this case, because all of the data values are very close together.  If you plot the data without scaling, the plot will look the same, except the y-axis range will be 1 - 10 instead.

  - This should really only be used in cases when the data is widely diverging, where an attribute will have too much influence with some ML algorithm.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

# path to file
p = Path(r'c:\some_path_to_file\breast-cancer-wisconsin.data')

# create dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(p, names=['id', 'clump_thickness','unif_cell_size',
                           'unif_cell_shape', 'marg_adhesion', 'single_epith_cell_size',
                           'bare_nuclei', 'bland_chromatin', 'normal_nucleoli','mitoses','Class'])

# replace ? with np.NaN
df.replace('?', np.NaN, inplace=True)

# scale the data
min_max_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
df_scaled = pd.DataFrame(min_max_scaler.fit_transform(df.iloc[:, 1:-1]))
df_scaled.columns = df.columns[1:-1]
df_scaled['Class'] = df['Class']

# melt the dataframe
df_scaled_melted = df_scaled.iloc[:, 1:].melt(id_vars='Class', var_name='Attributes', value_name='Values')

# plot the data
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
g = sns.boxplot(x='Attributes', y='Values', hue='Class', data=df_scaled_melted)
for item in g.get_xticklabels():
    item.set_rotation(90)
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Without scaling:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np

p = Path.cwd() / r'data\breast_cancer\breast-cancer-wisconsin.data'

df = pd.read_csv(p, names=['id', 'clump_thickness','unif_cell_size',
                           'unif_cell_shape', 'marg_adhesion', 'single_epith_cell_size',
                           'bare_nuclei', 'bland_chromatin', 'normal_nucleoli','mitoses','Class'])

df.replace('?', np.NaN, inplace=True)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df = df.astype('int')

df_melted = df.iloc[:, 1:].melt(id_vars='Class', var_name='Attributes', value_name='Values')

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
g = sns.boxplot(x='Attributes', y='Values', hue='Class', data=df_melted)
for item in g.get_xticklabels():
    item.set_rotation(90)
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

[image]